# How can I get MySQL to use the right index

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.6

I have a query on a table with almost 1.8M rows. I created an index `new_index` which includes all columns in the `WHERE` and `ORDER` clauses in order to improve performance. Now I issue the query:

```
select  col_1
    from  mytable
    where  col_1 in (1,2,6,8,9,22,26,28,29,30,31,34,35,36,37,
                     38,39,41,44,45,46,51,52,53,54,55,57,60 )
      and  col_2 in(1,4,6,10)
      and  (col_3 = 0)
      and  (      col_4 = 1
              or  col_4 = 2
           )
    order by  insert_time asc;
```

The sum of the handler reads (shown by `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`) is 1,781,069. Here's the output of the explain query. Surprisingly the chosen index is not the one I created but another one `mytable_ind_col_3`. It uses only one column.

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                                         | key                     | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable     | ref  | mytable_ind_11,mytable_ind_col_3,new_index | mytable_ind_col_3 | 5       | const | 892093 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

So I force MySQL to use my index:

```
select  col_1
    from  mytable use index (new_index)
    where  col_1 in (1,2,6,8,9,22,26,28,29,30,31,34,35,36,37,
                     38,39,41,44,45,46,51,52,53,54,55,57,60 )
      and  col_2 in(1,4,6,10)
      and  (col_3 = 0)
      and  (      col_4 = 1
              or  col_4 = 2
           )
    order by  insert_time asc;
```

Now the sum of the handler reads is 227. There are two interesting things about the explain query result. First, the row count is higher than for the first query, and I know from the handler counts that this is incorrect. What's confusing the optimizer? How can I fix it? Second, `key_len` is 20, I would expect it to be 25 (4 INTs + 1 datetime + 5 nullable columns). So I guess some columns are not being used. Why is that?

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable     | range | new_index        | new_index        | 20      | NULL | 1141728 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------+
```

`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_4` are all nullable INTs and `insert_time` is a nullable datetime. `new_index` is an index on (`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_4`, `insert_time`) and `mytable_ind_col_3` is an index on `col_3` only. This is on MySQL 5.6.

How can I get MySQL to use `new_index`, which seems to be the optimal solution, without forcing it?

Comment: The index is in no way optimal - one problem s that the only eq-ref in the query is (col_3 = 0). but col_3 is not first in the index, thats probably why the optimizer does not want to use it without hints.

Comment: Why is equality preferred over range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the datatypes and `new_index`.

For *that* query, I suggest

```
INDEX(col_3, col_1, col_2, col_4, insert_time)
```

I put `col_3` first because of the "=" test: `col_3 = 0`  The rest of the columns are there for "covering" (cf "Using index"), and the ordering may not matter.  That ordering *may* eliminate the need for `USE INDEX`.  There *will* be a sort.

If `mytable_ind_col_3` is `INDEX(col_3)`, `DROP` it when adding my index.  (Else the Optimizer may continue to use it.)

Comment: All these columns, except `insert_time`, are `int(11) DEFAULT NULL`. I tried your suggestion. The optimizer decided to use the index with (col_3, col_1, col_2, col_4), let's call it `ind1`, which is good. Then I built a new index with all those columns plus `insert_time` at the end, let's call it `ind2`. The optimizer preferred `ind1` to `ind2`, despite the fact the `ind2` would've saved it the sort. Why is that?

Comment: Also, why is having an equality test lead the index faster than a range test?

Comment: @Johnny - Again, since ind1 is the leading columns of ind2, the Optimizer mistakenly picked ind1.  So drop ind1 and keep ind2.  As for "=" -- All of the rows for col3=0 are adjacent in the index BTree, so, it can move on to the next column.  Ind2 is better than the others because it is "covering" -- all the needed columns are in it; no need to jump over to the data's BTree.

Comment: @Johnny - http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: @Johnny nothing will save the filesort in your case - equality first means that you can pick a subtree of the btee index that is again a (single) tree, with range (inequality, IN, OR) you get multiple such subtrees that you have to scan and that means many optimizations are out of the window at that level - including ORDER BY, because the multiple trees are each sorted separately

Comment: OK, now I understand the sort. But I still don't get why equality is better than range. Sure, you might need to scan more sub-trees, but wouldn't the fact that the DB uses SSDs make that irrelevant?

Comment: @Johnny - `=` rows are all together, but the ordering is dealt with by the next column in the Index.  `IN` rows are "some here", "some there".  'Range' rows are ordered.

Comment: @Johnny - Even with SSDs, I/O is still the biggest time-consumer.  If the buffer_pool is big enough, all the blocks may be cached in RAM; in this case, the number of rows (in the index or in the data BTree) is then next time-consumer, this time due to CPU.

Comment: @Johnny - And by "covering", only index rows need to be touched, not data rows.  (I really like the Handler numbers, but they fail to make this distinction.)